# mapping picklist field with numbers on import

Tags: picklist, leads, import, field-mapping

I would like to know if there a way to mapping Picklist field values to display as string when Import Excel sheet with number value for that field ?
Example
I've a lead with Picklist field "Are you ready to join?" and values are (Yes/No).

On Excel Sheet values came even 1 for yes or 0 for no.

Is there a way to mapping these values? I thinking about workflow on insert/update but maybe there a simple solution for this if I had more than one field like this.

sorry for my English !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to make the transformation *during* import. If you were importing to a checkbox, 1 and 0 would translate to checked and unchecked (respectively), but as a picklist, they are basically text values. You have two choices in regards how to handle this: fix the import file *before* importing, or use the built-in mass change tools in salesforce *after* importing.

For the first option, simply select the column in Excel, choose Find & Replace, and change 1 to Yes, and 0 to No. For the second option, import the file as is, then go to the field in Setup (e.g. Setup > Customize > Accounts > Fields, or Setup > Create > Objects), select "Replace" next to the field, and replace 1 with Yes and 0 with No.

Comment: Thank your for your detailed Answer, but sorry when Import field with value 0 (which not exist) I have only Yes or No. How this value will imported or sorted into picklist ? or you mean to create another text field to insert 0/1 values ?

Comment: @user3003810 Picklists will import any value you like, even those not present in the picklist. Just import the file, and use the Replace function afterwards to fix the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a before insert/update trigger. A workflow will cause triggers to fire again which is suitable if your organisation has a small code base however not very ideal in case your organisation has large code base with lots of triggers and queries.